# Why does the session value get deleted after the user deletes browser cookies?

Tags: php

How can we keep session value when user cookies are deleted?

```
 <?php
    session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['userdata']['name']='bikash';
?>
```

If user deletes the cookies, my session value has deleted. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other posters have mentioned the cookies contains the session id which is required to access the session. However unless you perform a `session_destroy()` the actual session data can be still found on the directory which session files are stored.

Comment: @ Devzer i think you are right, we can find the data from session handler location file. the previous data according to session ID right?

Answer (score 10):

Because the session ID is stored in a cookie. If the user deletes it, then you can't recover it.

Comment: you mean we can`t keep session value after delete the cookies

Comment: @BikashNayak, as I said in a separate comment, it is possible, but not in any secure way.

Comment: can any one explain the thing i can`t understand if session handler support in  PHP then why can`t we keep session value after delete the cookies value ?

Comment: @BikashNayak, the session data is stored on the server. Each session has an ID so it can be identified when the user makes a request. This ID is stored on the browser using a cookie, then the browser sends it along with each request. If the cookies are deleted, then the ID from the browser disappears and it won't know what it was anymore.

Comment: ok @Rid , secure purpose its ok, can you give some example how to keep?session value

Comment: @BikashNayak, if you want to send the session ID in the URL, then you could use something like `ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0); ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", 1);`. This way, the ID will be sent as part of the URL instead of being kept as a cookie. The problem with this approach though is that if you pass the URL to another person, then the other person will be logged in as yourself, since they have the session ID. So this is not at all recommended.

Comment: ok Rid, i got your point if we use database for save the session id can we retrieve session value?

Comment: @BikashNayak, yes, you can, if the browser can tell you what the ID is (you need to use the ID to find the session in the database, or wherever it's stored). But the browser doesn't know what the ID is anymore if it gets deleted with the cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Once cookie is deleted, session ID is deleted as well as it's in that cookie. There's no way to get session ID if cookie is deleted as per my knowledge

Comment: you mean we can`t keep session value after delete cookies

Comment: @BikashNayak, you could if you sent the session ID as part of the URL instead of in a cookie. But if you keep it in a cookie and the cookie is deleted, the session ID goes with it.

Comment: Agree. make session id part of url

Comment: @Shumail92, I'm not sure if this is something to be recommended though. It would fix the problem, but introduce many security issues.

Comment: Exactly that's why i didn't mention it first.

Comment: May be if @BikashNayak can tell problem or what is being tried to achieve, i can help

Comment: @Shumail ,some time user delete the browser cookies they do not know about session value. but in case user deleted the browser cookies for some other domain , that time we do not want to lost our session value.

Comment: @BikashNayak, if they delete the cookies only from another domain, yours will still be present.

Comment: @Shumail i got some knowledge as you answer gd and you can see Devzer answer i think it may be right answer

Comment: @Shumil thanks for answered but i have not more than 15 reputation when i reached then i ll do thanks

Answer (score 2):

As [rid already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17489014), the session identifier is stored within a cookie for every user. So when they delete their cookies, the session identifier is also gone, making it impossible for `session_start` to relaunch the previous session. Instead it will start a new one, with no data.

If you have some other means of assigning a previous session to a user, for example if you have a database that maps ip addresses to session ids (bad idea!), then you could restore the previous session id using `session_id()`.

Comment: can you see the answer of Devzer answer i think it may be right answer :) as i got both your clear the session data recover . thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The session ID it self is stored in a cookie.

If the user deletes it, then you cant access any information associated with the session because there's no way of referring to it.

In other words, you delete the browser cookies, the session is deleted since the session is stored as a cookie!

Comment: you mean we can`t keep session value after delete the cookies?

Comment: no, the actual data can still be recovered from the directory where the session files are stored, why do you wanna delete the cookie, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You can't recover sessoin id if cookie is deleted as it's in cookie.